# Is this a valid identifier for a sql table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, identifier

I made a mistake renaming a table column using the SP_RENAME store procedure and now I cannot revert it. Is this a valid identifier for SQL Server?

[image]

This is what I did:

```
SP_RENAME '[WTF].[Name]', '[WhatThisFunction]', 'COLUMN'
```

Then, after see the unexpected result I tried to roll it back with

```
SP_RENAME '[WTF].[WhatThisFunction]', 'Name', 'COLUMN'
```

But sql says the object cannot be found. Is there any way to escape the brackets?

**Update:**
The error message is:
Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 215
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: I think you just need to bracket '[Name]'

Comment: @Martin, thank you. It is exactly the same question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
SP_RENAME '[WTF].[[WhatThisFunction]]]', 'Name', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the answer was deleted but this script will in fact change the column's name back to "name".

```
SP_RENAME '[WTF]."[WhatThisFunction]"', 'name', 'COLUMN'
```

So will

```
SP_RENAME '[WTF].[[WhatThisFunction]]]', 'Name', 'COLUMN'
```

as listed by user1948904.

The reason you ended up with a problem in the first place (and I've done the same thing) is that the first parameter for sp_rename can have []'s or not, if you put []'s on the second parameter then that is going to be included in the name.  So the name of your column became [WhatThisFunction] instead of WhatThisFunction which is probably what you intended.

Interestingly if you go into the design window the column name is actually listed as [[WhatThisFunction]]] and when you script out the change it pass that to sp_rename.